# php: only register visit 1 per hour

Tags: php

How can i only save one profilevisit per hour? So if you visited at 10:10 then it wont save when you view the profile at 12:10 ?

My code right now that saves evrytime you visit:

```
$date = time();
$BuID= mysql_real_escape_string($v["id"]);
$uID= mysql_real_escape_string($showU["id"]);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_profilevisits (uID, BuID, date) VALUES ('$uID', '$BuID', '$date')") or
                die(mysql_error());
```

update

```
function save(){
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_profilevisits (uID, BuID, date) VALUES ('$uID', '$BuID', '$date')") or
                die(mysql_error());
    $_SESSION['saved']=time();
 }

 if(isset($_SESSION['saved'])){
     $time = time();
     if($time-$_SESSION['saved'] > 3600){
        save();
        }
 }else{
    save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select the timestamp and conditionally execute the save based on timestamp. alternatively, set a session variable and conditionally execute based on that value.

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['saved']){
     $time = time();
     if($time-$_SESSION['saved'] > 3600){
        save($uid,$buid);
 }else{
    save($uid,$buid);

 function save($uid,$buid){
    //save stuff here
    $_SESSION['saved']=time();
 }
```

Comment: So i should store a session variable after inserting to database. Then check if the session variable is set or not (in order to execute the query) ? But how can i put a timer on the session variable lasting for one hour only? quick example?

Comment: i get alot of errors, but i fixed them and now i dont get any errors. It still doesnt work. see updated question for code

Comment: @user otherwise update in the database field  and then use Brandon code.Instead of $_SESSION['saved'] replace $row['yourfieldname'].But that is not advisable due to time consuming.

Comment: still need to set the variables for your query in the save function

Comment: it inserts, but not $uID and $BuID gets 0 in value because its inside that function. What can i do?

Answer (score 3):

If you always set the minutes/seconds of the provided time to 0, you can create a key over **date** and **BuID**, so it wont be able to insert more than 1 row within a hour(without any checks, session-vars or subqueries).

If you need the minutes/seconds for further operations, create a new column for implementing the described method.

assuming the following table:

```
date INT(11)  
uID INT(11)  
BuID INT(11)  
date2 TIMESTAMP  
UNIQUE KEY `BuID` (`BuID`,`date2`)
```

the following query should match your needs:

```
INSERT INTO users_profilevisits (uID, BuID, date, date2) 
 VALUES ('$uID', '$BuID', '$date',FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y%m%d%H0000'))
```

As you have a unique key over BuID and date2(date2 will have a value of the current time with minutes and seconds set to 0), it wont be able to insert duplicate rows with the same date2+BuID

But you have to remove the `or die()` , because if you try to insert a duplicate key, this will result in an error.

Using this method you dont need a programming logic, the table-structure itsselve will do the work for you.

Comment: Hello. Your first method, I cant work on, because i want the users to see his old's dates.

Comment: Instead of 10 rows because he visited you 10 times within a hour, it should only register the first time.

Comment: Edited my post, hope it's more plausible now.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the MySQL table an additional field and set it to unique. When you save the visit, save a string like "visitoruserid+year+month+day+hour" to that field. That way MySQL takes care of only allowing one per hour per user without the need for additional PHP code, sessions and time checks.

Edit:

Add. benefit: If you later choose to loose the "once per hour" condition or change it to once per day or add more conditions, you only have to change the string saved to that field without any more changes to your code.